# AWS lambda trying to access ec2 and getting timeout

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

There is an ec2 instance in aws which has an API, I am trying to access the APIs using lambda but getting time out.

The lambda I created has the same VPC, subnet and security group. Along with this I have also give permission in the inbound rule of the ec2 which is allow all traffic from the security group of lambda. Still when I am send a post request to the api I am getting the timeout.

What am I going wrong?

PS: I can access these api from my local sending a post request though.

Comment: What URL are you trying to send the request to? A public or a private one?

Comment: Are you accessing via a URL or an IP address?

Comment: I am using the public IP address.

Comment: Your lambda probably has no internet access. https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function or maybe the security group does not allow outbound connections.

Answer (score 0):

To access resources within your VPC you need to specify subnets and/or security for your lambda-function and add the Execution Role to your Lambda.

1. It sounds like you've already done this but double check that the security group associated with the EC2 allows traffic from the either the **security group** associated with the Lambda, or you could use the **VPC CIDR** (a private IP range x.x.x.x/16).
2. Add `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` to your Lambda

> AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole is an AWS managed policy that: Provides minimum permissions for a Lambda function to execute while accessing a resource within a VPC [1]

[1] AWS Documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-managed-policy/latest/reference/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole.html